# Is it possible to perform multiple replacements in one function call?

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

If you want to replace multiple strings in one go, you can of course nest the REPLACE function, eg. like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(foo, 'apple', 'fruit'), 'banana', 'fruit'), 'lettuce', 'vegetable')
FROM bar
```

If you have to do a lot of replacing, your code will become ugly and hard to read. Is there such a thing as a multi-replace function? Which would maybe take 2 arrays as arguments? To be sure, I'm familiar with the TRANSLATE function, but as my example indicates I want to replace whole words, not just single characters.

Comment: You can do this with a recursive CTE.

Comment: probably possible with regex -- but I doubt it would be faster.  Sometimes data will be easy to work with by casting to xml and using xml extensions on it -- that might work.

Comment: Are you looking for performance or "clean"-ness? For performance do what you're doing. For cleanliness create a function that does what you want and use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement such a function in the following way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multi_replace(_string text, variadic _param_args text[])                                     
  RETURNS TEXT 
AS    
$BODY$    
DECLARE
  _index integer;
BEGIN
  FOR _index IN 1 .. cardinality(_param_args) - 1 by 2 loop
    _string := replace(_string, _param_args[_index], _param_args[_index+1]);
  end loop;
  RETURN _string;            
END;         
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

`cardinality()` returns the length of the parameter array, and `by 2` increases the loop index by 2 for every iteration so that it's safe to use `_index` and `_index + 1` inside the loop to access the pairs that belong together.

Online example: https://rextester.com/LITG61720

Comment: But it doesn't work as expected when a replacement string matches a search term coming after. Example: `multi_replace('I love bar and baz', 'bar', 'bazinga', 'baz', 'music')` will produce `I love musicinga and music` instead of the expected `I love bazinga and music`.

Comment: That is actually expected behavior Daniel, considering that the function is supposed to do the same as multiple (nested) replace functions (as posited in my question). If you need a function that does singular ordered replaces, I recommend you ask a new question (and maybe link to this one to save everybody time).

Comment: I just realized while looking at this function (again) that the volatility should probably be set to "immutable", not "volatile". Don't know if it will make a big difference in performance, but I guess it won't hurt either (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for cleanliness, not performance, so I went with your suggestion 404.

This is the function I wrote:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multi_replace(  
                                        _string                 TEXT,
                                        VARIADIC _param_args    TEXT[]
                                        )                                     
RETURNS TEXT AS    
$BODY$    
    DECLARE
            _old        RECORD;
            _new        TEXT;    
    BEGIN
        FOR _old in     (
                        SELECT 
                            _param_args[i]                      AS tekst, 
                            i                                   AS indexnummer
                        FROM  generate_series(1, 5, 2) i
                        )                           
                        LOOP 
                            _new    := COALESCE(_param_args[_old.indexnummer+1], '');
                            _string := REPLACE(_string, _old.tekst, _new);
                        END LOOP;    
        RETURN _string;            
    END;         
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

And this is a sample call:

```
select multi_replace('I love to drink milk in the morning', 'milk', 'beer', 'morning', 'evening', 'I', 'we');
```

Odd that this isn't a standard function, maybe a good idea for the next release? Thanks everybody for the suggestions!

Comment: You don't need the `generate_series()`. You can [loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) over the input array directly or use `unnest(..) with ordinality`

Comment: Interesting, thanks. How would I deal with determining which elements are to be replaced and which ones are replacement values?

Comment: @horse very neat, I learned something today! I'd like to make your comment the accepted answer, if I only knew how.